# AudioUnit Input Samples

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, audiounit

So I am having some trouble here with my AudioUnit taking in data from microphone/line-in in iOS. I am able to set everything up to what I think is okay and it is calling my recordingCallback, but the data that I am getting out of the buffer is not correct. It always returns exactly the same thing, which is mostly zeros and random large numbers. Does anyone know what could be causing this. My code is as follows.

**Setting up Audio Unit**

```
OSStatus status;

// Describe audio component
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

// Get component
AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);
status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &audioUnit);

// Enable IO for recording
UInt32 flag = 1;
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              kInputBusNumber,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));
// Disable playback IO
flag = 0;
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              kOutputBusNumber,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));

// Describe format
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked |kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 32;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 4;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 4;

// Apply format
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                              kInputBusNumber, 
                              &audioFormat, 
                              sizeof(audioFormat));

// Set input callback
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                              kInputBusNumber, 
                              &callbackStruct, 
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));
status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);
```

**Input Callback**

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = 4;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(sizeof(float)*inNumberFrames); //
    InputAudio *input = (__bridge InputAudio*)inRefCon;

    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioUnitRender([input audioUnit], 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             &bufferList);

    float* result = (float*)&bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData;

    if (input->counter == 5) {
        for (int i = 0;i<inNumberFrames;i++) {
            printf("%f ",result[i]);
        }
    }
    input->counter++;
    return noErr;
}
```

Anyone ever encounter a similar problem or see something clearly wrong in my code. Thanks in advance for any help!

I am basing all of it off of [Michael Tysons Core Audio RemoteIO code](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/)

Comment: This is from a while ago but just in case someone sees this and copies the code: you should not use malloc in time-sensitive code. Allocate the buffer elsewhere. (or lazily alloc it once.)

Comment: I think that mDataByteSize should be set to the total number of bytes in the buffer, rather than the size of each sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the samples you get from the audio buffer in the callback aren't floats, they're SInt16. Try casting the samples like this:

```
SInt16 *sn16AudioData= (SInt16 *)(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData);
```

And these should be the max and min values:

```
#define sn16_MAX_SAMPLE_VALUE 32767
#define sn16_MIN_SAMPLE_VALUE -32768
```

Comment: I do that as well, just in this example I forgot to change it back to SInt16. It seems to keep returning me just crap data that I can not use at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was basically trying to do the same thing with very similar code but using an `AudioGraph()`. I had the same problem, zeros in my output data from the mic and could not get it working until I added the line

```
Status = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, ioNode, 1, ioNode, 0);
```

As you are not using a graph you will need to call `AudioUnitSetProperty()` with `kAudioUnitProperty_MakeConnectio`n and pass and pass a complete AudioUnitConnection structure

Comment: Would I be able to get a copy of the code you are using? If so, let me know, and I will give you my email address.

Comment: Yes, my website is [link](http://www.zippysystems.com) goto the contact us page. I will send you the create function.